# Looking to replace Adobe Acrobat Reader with something that prioritizes usability over cost

Tags: gratis, open-source, pdf

With how Adobe's changed with each new iteration and how more and more features have been placed behind a paywall, what are some programs that allow a user the basic functionality of creating/editing fields and importing/exporting with data that plays nicely with MS applications? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Adobe Reader is for displaying PDFs. Was it ever possible to create forms with it? That was Adobe "Writer", not Reader, wasn't it?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Reading: https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer
Editting: https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor

unless you update your question to give us a list of required features. I have used these for years and am very satisfied; have searched regularly for "better" alternatives and found none (for my personal list of requirements - YKmMV).

Please read [how to ask](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and remember Garbage In, Garbage Out. The more detail you give us about your requirements, the better answers you will get.

Please help us to help you.